# How to change status of pin in Spartan 3E FPGA

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, spartan-3

**Verilog Code:**

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module blink (customClk, LED, statusPIN);

input customClk;
output statusPIN;
output LED;

reg [31:0] counter;
reg LED_status;

initial begin
counter <= 32'b0;
LED_status <= 1'b0;
end

always @ (posedge customClk) 
begin
counter <= counter + 1'b1;
if (counter > 5000)
begin
LED_status <= !LED_status;
counter <= 32'b0;
end


end

assign LED = LED_status;
assign statusPIN = LED_status;

endmodule
```

**UCF File:**

```
NET "LED" LOC = F12;
NET "LED" IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33;
NET "statusPIN" LOC = E8;
NET "statusPIN" IOSTANDARD = LVTTL;
```

**Testbench code:**

```
module main_tb;

    // Inputs
    reg customClk;

    // Outputs
    wire LED;
    wire statusPIN;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    blink uut (
        .customClk(customClk), 
        .LED(LED), 
        .statusPIN(statusPIN)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        customClk = 0;
        
        // Add stimulus here

    end
    always #10 customClk = ~customClk;
      
endmodule
```

LED is blinking too fast but when I read the status of the pin, it is still low. Where is the problem in code.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A "counter" is a synchronous circuit. It has clock. You don't have clock in your design.

Comment: I added the testbench but in simulation, customClk is always high

Comment: If LED is blinking fast, you should figure out what's the source clock frequency and to which frequency, your 5000-counter is dividing it down.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an

```
always @(posedge clk)
```

block. "always @(*)" is only for combinatorial logic but you have to build synchronous logic to make a counter. With "posedge" your always-block only gets triggered once per clock cycle.

Comment: I added the testbench but in simulation, customClk is always high